# How to give input to a task

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I've created a task in my testbench which takes 3 inputs, but it seems that the value of one of them is wrong.

Below there is my code. I already know that `s` has the same value of `dut.r.f`, but when I run the simulation it's not like this.

MAIN:

```
module main(
  input  logic        clk,
  input logic         vaux2_p,
  input logic         vaux2_n,
  output  logic        gpio1,
);

  logic [8:0] f;

inst r(
    .clk                    (clk),
    .f                      (f),
  );

endmodule
```

R:

```
module inst(
  input  logic         clk,
output logic [ 8:0] f
);

always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    f <= 8'h0_F0;
end

endmodule
```

TESTBENCH:

```
module m();
  logic        clk;
  logic        vaux2_p;
  logic        vaux2_n;
  logic        gpio1;

  main dut(
    .clk(clk),
    .vaux12_p (vaux2_p),
    .vaux12_n (vaux2_n),
    .gpio1 (gpio1)
    );

  task test;
    input [ 7:0] a;
    input [8:0] v;
    input [8:0] s;
    integer f1;
       begin
          f1 = $fopen("file.txt","w");
          if (!f1) begin
             $display("File \"file.txt\" cannot be opened!");
          end else begin
          //this part of code is just for test what I'm reading
          $fdisplay(f1," f: %0h %0b %0d", dut.r.f,dut.r.f,dut.r.f);
          $fdisplay(f1,"s: %0h %0b %0d", s,s,s);
          $fdisplay(f1,"v: %0h %0b %0d", v,v,v);
          $fclose(f1);            
     end
  endtask

  initial begin

    test(8'h19,24'hFF00, dut.r.f);
$finish;
  end
endmodule
```

If I run this code and then I open the file.txt what I can read is this:

```
f: f0 11110000 240
s: xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx x
v: f0 11110000 240
```

I was thinking that this can be due to the fact that at the beginning of the simulation `dut.r.f=xxxxxx` and only after few `ns` it turns in `f0`, but then I realized that this cannot be the problem for two reasons: the first one is that if the value of the signals is taken at the beginning of the simulation, also `f` should be equal to `xxxxxx`, the second one is that even if I introduce a delay before I display the signal values, the problem still exists.
Do you know if there is any issue in passing a variable from main as input for the task? If yes, it's the same also with functions?
Can anyone kindly help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: this example is **not** compilable. instance 'dut' of module 'inst' contains  a wrong list of ports. please fix it first.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just new in verilog. What do you mean with wrong port list? For the dut the ports are the ones I wrote, while in the inst I have just tried to semplify the code not declaring ports that I don't need for what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is task input arguments get passed by value only when entering the `task test`. Further updates to the actual arguments to not get passed through. You need to use pass by reference to see later updates.. Change you task declaration to

```
 task test(
    input logic [ 7:0] a,
    input logic [8:0] v,
    ref logic  [8:0] s);
    int f1;
```

See [this post](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/what-meant-reference-argument-must-be-automatic#reply-41381) for more details.

Comment: I've also tried to pass it as reference, but still have the error

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your provided test bench is complete, the fundamental problem is the clock that `dut.r.f` is dependent on never toggles.

```
initial begin
  clk = 1'b0; // init clock;
  #1; // time to propagate
  clk = 1'b1; // will trigger @(posedge clk) if connected properly
  #1; // time to propagate
  test(8'h19,24'hFF00, dut.r.f);
  $finish;
end
```

If you want to start the task before toggling the clock, you will need to use SystemVerilog's `ref` instead of `input` as mentioned in dave_59's answer, and add time delay.